# Color of button read only error

Tags: wpf, button, colors

I am a little perplexed here with the actions of WPF. I can change the text of a button but can't change the color, it is giving a read only property error. Seems like something is wrong in design. Text changes color throws error.

```
svrSmtp.Stop()

btnStartServer.Background.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty)
btnStartServer.Content = "Start Proxy"
```

Comment: It's fine to set the background colour of a button to Null, it just draws a plain looking button.

Comment: Or try setting it with a new SolidColorBrush with a value of #00...... with the dots as a HEX-code of a color but it doesn't matter since the 00 indicate an Alpha-value of 0

Comment: yes, setting it to red worked, thanks. was trying to do it wrong I suppose, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to clear the value of Button.Background on the Button, not on it's background property.

```
btnStartServer.ClearValue (Button.BackgroundProperty);
```